# When swapping rows in a matrix, what happens to the numerical range?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, finite-fields

What effect does the operation of swapping rows in a matrix have on the matrix's numerical range? Whatever the result is, is it the same for matrices over finite fields?

Thanks,

Derek

Comment: How do you define [numerical range](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_range) over a finite field?

Comment: It's fairly recent, but it's the same concept. See section 2 of my paper with students here https://acmsonline.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/proceedings-2019.pdf

Didn't get as far as we liked. Anyway, it was initiated by Patrick X. Rault and some undergrads by a paper called "Numerical Range over Finite Fields" in a 2016 paper but it's behind a paywall (Linear Algebra & Applications). So you can get the definitions from our paper linked above.

Comment: I think the only invariant property is the numerical radius, that is the point of the numerical range with gratest norm, since it correspond to the spectral norm of the matrix

Comment: What is the conjugate of a number in $\mathbb Z_p$? in the article it is not explained

Comment: Exodd, the field has $p^2$ elements; the field is $\mathbb{Z}_p[i]$, with $p = 3 \mod 4$ to avoid anything but $i$ squaring to $-1$. So, the conjugate of $a+bi$ is $a-bi$.